# intersection of two dataTables in vb.net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

How to intersect two dataTables in vb.net 2.0?

I want to get common rows in two datatables and add it in third datatable.

Comment: I would do it in dbms if possible.

Comment: Tim, I cant do that in query cause first i have to check if the second query for datatable 2 returns rows then only i will intersect both the datatable else i will use datatable 1 data only.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite complex task. I'd suggest you to convert the data into native objects like this.

```
Public Sub Intersect(dtFirst As DataTable, dtSecond As DataTable)
    Dim first As List(Of MyObject) = ConvertToObjects(dtFirst)
    Dim second As List(Of MyObject) = ConvertToObjects(dtSecond)
    Dim result = first.Except(second, New MyObjectsComparer())
            ' Do whatever with the result
            ' You can convert the result back to datatable and save it to DB
End Sub

Private Function ConvertToObjects(dtFirst As DataTable) As List(Of MyObject)
    ' Conversion logic
    ' goes here
End Function
```

You'll be needing a custom comparer, because an `Except` method uses reference equality by default.

```
Public Class MyObjectsComparer
Implements IEqualityComparer(Of MyObject)

Public Overloads Function Equals(x As MyObject, y As MyObject) As Boolean
    Return (x.PrimaryKey = y.PrimaryKey)
End Function

Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As MyObject) As Integer
    Return obj.PrimaryKey.GetHashCode()
End Function
End Class
```

This comparer class implies that if two primary keys of your data are equal then the two objects are equal.